# Problem with gettting inf values in integral solution

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x87

The problem is that I get Infinium values after linking & execution. I need to solve integral from(sin(100*x)/x) on the interval [0,5] with Simpson's method. The file on **C** uses the **NASM** module to do calculations.  How to fix it?

**C:**
*the main program*

```
#include <stdio.h>
float sum(float a, float b);
float fx(float x);
int main() {
    float res = 0;
    float a = 0;
    float b = 3;
    float h = 0;
    float tmp1 = 0;
    float tmp2 = 0;
    float tmp3 = 0;
    float n = 5;
    float res2 = 0;
    h = (b - a)/n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i = i + 1){
        tmp1 = a + i*h;
        tmp2 = a + (i+1)*h;
        tmp3 = (tmp2-tmp1)/6.0*(fx(tmp1) + 4 * fx(0.5 * (tmp1 + tmp2))+ fx(tmp2));
        res = sum(res,tmp3);
        printf("%f\n", res);
    }
    
    printf("%f\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

**ASM:**
*the module on assembler (NASM)*

```
global sum
global fx
section .data
section .bss
    temp: resb 4
section .text
; float Fint(float x, float y)
; return x + y
sum:
    finit
    fld dword [esp + 8] ; st0 = x
    fadd dword [esp + 4] ; st0 += y
    
    ret ; returns st0 to c

; float fx(float x)
; return sin(100*x)/x

SinX:
    fld     qword [eax]           
    fsin                          
    fstp    qword [ebx]           
    ret
    
fx:
    ; st1 100*x
    fld dword [esp + 4] ; st1 = x
    mov dword [temp], 100
    fmul dword [temp] ; st1 *= 100
    
    ;sin(100*x)
    ;call SinX
    fsin
    
    ; st0
    mov dword [temp], 1
    fild dword [temp] ; st0 = 1
    fdiv st0, st1 ; st0 /= st1
    
    ret ;returns st0 to c
```

**(problem!)Result:**
inf
inf
inf
inf
inf
inf

Comment: You can start by getting rid of the `finit` in `sum`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Then they need to balance their pushes and pops to keep from overflowing the very limited floating-point stack.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're writing x87 code?  SSE is a lot more convenient and efficient, and is supported by basically every x86 processor made in the last 20 years.  If it doesn't specifically have to be in assembly, you'll probably do better still by just rewriting in C; modern compilers handle such things quite well.

Comment: Oh, I see why, because you want to be able to use the hardware `fsin`; true, SSE hasn't got that.  But these days it is probably faster to just call the library's `sin` function.  The `fsin` instruction is rarely used and therefore not well optimized in hardware.